# Prolog: store results from transitive relationship into list

Tags: prolog, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, reasoning

I am new to Prolog and now I have to implement a path consistency algorithm for RCC8 calculus/Allen Time Interval Algebra in Prolog.

I am struggling with basic problems. A small example of my Background Knowledge. It is all about a given transitivity table and computing the resulting constraints between regions:

```
tpp(a,b). 
dc(b,c).
dc(A,C) :- dc(A,C).
dc(A,C) :- tpp(A,B), dc(B,C).
```

So the constraint `dc(a,c).` should be generated. The whole algorithm:

```
Input: A network T
Output: A path consisten network
repeat
S <- T
for k:=1 to n do
    for i,j := 1 to n do begin
        Cij <- Cij UNION Cik COMPOSITION Ckj
until S = T
```

where Cij is the constraint between the nodes i and j. In the case of the BK tpp(a,b) for example. So my qeustion is, I am struggeling writing a rule which computes the resulting constraint from the transitivity table. I want to start with something like this:

```
comp([tpp(a,b), dc(b,c)], X).
```

Which stores `dc(a,c)` in X and I get `X = [dc(a,c)]` back.
I don't know if it is the right approach. I want to have a rule to which I give a list of constraints and it computes all resulting constraints. I am used to program in Python and Java and now I am struggeling starting with the problem.

Thank you very much! :D

Comment: Remove `dc(A,C) :- dc(A,C).`, as from a theoretical point of view it is a tautology, and from a practical point of view it doesn't add anything to your KB, and worse, it makes impossible to prove certain facts (`dc(a,c)`).

Comment: And from a practical point of view, `dc(A,C) :- dc(A,C).` will directly cause an infinite loop. You need to name your facts differently than your rule/predicate. For example, assert `dc_(b,c).` as a fact, and use rules, `dc(A,B) :- dc_(A,B).` and `dc(A,C) :- tpp(A,B), dc(B,C).`.